# CSV import into MySQL truncated - more data than columns

Tags: mysql, csv, import, truncated

sorry if it seems that it has been answered a lot of times, but spent many hours trying to figure it out. I have a complicated import from CSV into MySQL. My CSV files are generated in different software and changing it would be impossible.

My import code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'krupka_lezaky.csv'
INTO TABLE table_lezaky_krupka5 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@var1, @var2, NAZEV, DOPLNEK, @var5, @var6, @var7, @var8, @var9, @var10, @var11, @var12)
SET 
    ID_ZBOZI = REPLACE(@var1, '"', ''), -- Remove double quotes
    ID_CISELNIK = REPLACE(@var2, '"', ''), -- Remove double quotes
    MNOZSTVI = REPLACE(REPLACE(@var5, ',', '.'), '"', ''), -- Remove double quotes and commas
    NCENA_BD = REPLACE(REPLACE(@var6, ',', '.'), '"', ''),
    NCENA_SD = REPLACE(REPLACE(@var7, ',', '.'), '"', ''),
    PCENA_SD = REPLACE(REPLACE(@var8, ',', '.'), '"', ''),
    PCENA_RP = REPLACE(REPLACE(@var9, ',', '.'), '"', ''),
    DAT_PRIJEM = STR_TO_DATE(@var10, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'),
    DAT_VYDEJ = STR_TO_DATE(@var11, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'),
    KOD_VZP = REPLACE(@var12, '"', ''), -- Remove double quotes
    ID_PROVOZOVNA = 4; -- Set the fixed value for the 13th column
```

My table format:

[image]

My table code:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_lezaky_krupka5` (
  `ID_ZBOZI` int NOT NULL,
  `ID_CISELNIK` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAZEV` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOPLNEK` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MNOZSTVI` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NCENA_BD` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NCENA_SD` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PCENA_SD` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PCENA_RP` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DAT_PRIJEM` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DAT_VYDEJ` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `KOD_VZP` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_PROVOZOVNA` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_ZBOZI`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

My csv file:

```
"ID_ZBOZI","ID_CISELNIK","NAZEV","DOPLNEK","MNOZSTVI","NCENA_BD","NCENA_SD","PCENA_SD","PCENA_RP","DAT_PRIJEM","DAT_VYDEJ","KOD_VZP"
"11311782","*","5PreveMax Imunit nukleotidy+betaglukan","tbl 60+20","1,0000","238,5000","274,2800","365,0000","365,0000","21.07.2022 07:34:57","14.07.2022 14:32:58",""
"15100001","1","ACYLCOFFIN","POR TBL NOB 10","6,0000","307,0100","337,7300","470,0000","470,0000","20.07.2022 08:08:38","10.02.2023 11:07:09","9"
"15103351","1","AERIUS 5 MG","TBL 30X5MG","1,0000","109,9100","120,9000","160,0000","160,0000","27.07.2022 07:55:40","26.07.2022 07:55:05","26329"
"15144399","1","AESCULUS HIPPOCASTANUM","GRA 4GM 5CH","2,0000","148,3200","163,1600","230,0000","230,0000","06.01.2021 08:30:50","","62741"
"15100094","1","AGOLUTIN","INJ 5X2ML/60MG","1,0000","55,7400","61,3100","70,0000","70,0000","11.02.2022 08:13:57","07.02.2022 14:58:29","186149"
"15103137","*","Alpa bylinný masážní gel kaštan ","100ml","1,0000","35,5700","43,0400","65,0000","65,0000","23.12.2022 10:15:38","22.12.2022 09:14:17",""
"15102019","*","Alpa emulze s arnikou ","100ml","2,0000","81,1200","98,1600","138,0000","138,0000","15.02.2023 07:51:23","14.02.2023 10:51:55",""
"15104744","1","AMPRILAN 5","TBL 30X5MG","1,0000","23,6000","25,9600","34,0000","34,0000","23.12.2022 10:15:25","22.12.2022 16:29:00","23962"
"15120270","1","ANALERGIN NEO","5MG TBL FLM 90 II","1,0000","195,7900","215,3700","283,0000","283,0000","23.09.2022 06:48:38","22.09.2022 11:23:23","201946"
```

Error:

`Error Code: 1262. Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns`

I guess my problem is formatting of the CSV file, we use commas as decimal separator, then my decimal values get double quotes as well. I tried to get around it, used replacements to get the right format, but still getting error. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You don't need `REPLACE(@var1, '"', '')`. When you say `ENCLOSED BY '"'` the quotes will be removed automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal values get double parentheses"? Parentheses are `()`. Did you mean extra quotes?

Comment: Please post the CSV file as text, not a screenshot, so we can copy and paste.

Comment: Because the screenshot looks like it has the correct number of fields.

Comment: I am sorry for confusion, i meant double quotes "", I edited the original post

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for your table. Screenshot does not give enough data and cannot be used for to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Done, next time I will provide code at first place, thank you for your time

Comment: I do not see any problem, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrYV5.png). I use your table definition, CSV content and LOAD DATA query. In the query I have changed the file pathname (complete pathname is specified) and lines terminator (I use Windows system). PS. Try to specify complete file pathname.

Comment: @Akina I guess the problem was partially in the like termination, I didn't know I have to use "\r\n" for Windows...

Comment: now I see there might be problem with my location...now I get an error "Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date", when I Try to input fixed value into date in format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" I guess it may work, becaude I get another error:  "Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"Alpa bylinn'
" so I guess the problem is coding of text?

Comment: *when I Try to input fixed value into date in format "`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`"* Maybe it's a time not to imagine your own syntax but study the data pattern definition which is used by MySQL? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: fair enough, but I just wanted to let you know what I tried...because obviously the code worked for you, so the format should be good...but I got this "Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date", that is why I tried to get around it thinking there may be a problem with this line of code. Sadly I still cannot import my csv

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for trying to help, I think I finally found a solution.
There were two problems,

1. some of dates in the CSV file were null, so the str_to_date resulted in error, making a condition there helped (at least that is the reason that I think)
2. I resaved the CSV file in UTF-8 coding, it seems that the original file was in ANSI coding

my code is this now:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'hranik_lezaky.csv'
INTO TABLE table_lezaky_hranik
CHARACTER SET latin1 -- Assuming ANSI encoding is similar to ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@var1, @var2, NAZEV, DOPLNEK, @var5, @var6, @var7, @var8, @var9, @var10, @var11, @var12)
SET 
    ID_ZBOZI = @var1,
    ID_CISELNIK = @var2,
    MNOZSTVI = REPLACE(@var5, ',', '.'),
    NCENA_BD = REPLACE(@var6, ',', '.'),
    NCENA_SD = REPLACE(@var7, ',', '.'),
    PCENA_SD = REPLACE(@var8, ',', '.'),
    PCENA_RP = REPLACE(@var9, ',', '.'),
    DAT_PRIJEM = IF(@var11 <> '', STR_TO_DATE(@var11, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), NULL),
    DAT_VYDEJ = IF(@var11 <> '', STR_TO_DATE(@var11, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), NULL),
    KOD_VZP = @var12,
    ID_PROVOZOVNA = 1; -- Set the fixed value for the 13th column
```

finally, I managed to import the data, now I will try to change the coding of imported CSV file in this code

EDIT// DONE, thanks :)